Is it possible to install ubuntu 24.04 on a nvme multi boot system?
I have installed Ubuntu at least 20 times but the new installer is a mystery. I have a NVMe with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 23.04 and an empty partition slot of 45 Gb (was Ubuntu 22.04). I used to switch two 45 Gb partitions every time I made a new install. Installing the root in that slot and a /home on a hard drive. Grub used to just ad the new OS and I would be up and running in 30 minutes or so.
So I leave 23.04 untouched when I install 24.04 so I can use it if there is problems with 24.04. How is that done with the new installer?

Please add more details on which exact product you are trying to install. There are so many different installers in use and they all have their quirks.

It is not clear if you are using a desktop or the server version. They use different installer. Note in this Q&A site questions are answered by other users like you and me, not Canonical. If you add some screenshots or pictures of the screen during installation and explain where you are having problems we can try to answer. If you just want to rant to the Ubuntu developers, this is not the place.

It is the desktop version  (the server version with multi boot?) and this has nothing to do with hardware brand. The issue is that to get the install started after picking / and /home partition before I would press install and that was that, but now the installer demands a new partitioning of the NVMe (unless I have missed something, which is why I am asking). It says this can be rolled back but also the existing will be deleted. I do not trust that rolling it back will work when it does not seem to take the logical "old" route (and I can not see why it needs a new partitioning either).

Answering this would mean that you have actually got the installer to install on an existing multi OS hard drive or NVMe. I can get it to install a new multi boot install but not onto an existing one... hope that clears it up. Oh yah this is GPT.

I am installing 24.04.01

So the solution was to use Ubuntu-Mate. Their installer works and all was done in under 30 minutes. What a joke that Ubuntu can not make a working installer, just like Microsoft 25 years ago. Thanks to those that toke the time to read my question...

So the solution was to use Ubuntu-Mate. Their installer works and all was done in under 30 minutes. Thanks to those that toke the time to read my question...
